# QWebEngineView добавить куки

Tags: python, pyqt5

Сделал QWebEngineView и открываю ссылку следующим образом:

```
self.widget.setUrl(QUrl(link))
```

Не могу понять как перед открытием ссылки добавить cookie вида:

```
cookie: foo=bar;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот нашел такой способ

```
self.profile = QWebEngineProfile("storage", self.widget)
    self.cookie_store = self.profile.cookieStore()
    ck = 'foo=bar;'
    for c in ck.split("; "):
        c = c.split("=")
        self.ok = QNetworkCookie()
        self.ok.setDomain("ok.ru")
        self.ok.setName(bytes(c[0], encoding="utf-8"))
        self.ok.setValue(bytes(c[1], encoding="utf-8"))
        self.cookie_store.setCookie(self.ok)
    self.webpage = QWebEnginePage(self.profile, self.widget)
    self.widget.setPage(self.webpage)
    self.widget.setUrl(QUrl(link))
```